# Animating car Marker movement returns to north when stopped

Tags: java, android, google-maps, location, android-animation

I am animating car moving on a street with real time location updates. While moving it positions correctly towards the direction, but when the movement stops the car is facing to true north and the bearing returns 0.0 no matter which direction I am. Follow the code I'm using:

```
public static void animateMarker(Marker marker, Location destination) {
    if (marker != null) {
        LatLng startPosition = marker.getPosition();
        LatLng endPosition = new LatLng(destination.getLatitude(), destination.getLongitude());

        float startRotation = marker.getRotation();

        LatLngInterpolator latLngInterpolator = new LatLngInterpolator.LinearFixed();
        ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1);
        valueAnimator.setDuration(1000); // duration 1 second
        valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(animation -> {
            try {
                float v = animation.getAnimatedFraction();
                LatLng newPosition = latLngInterpolator.interpolate(v, startPosition, endPosition);
                marker.setPosition(newPosition);
                marker.setRotation(computeRotation(v, startRotation, destination.getBearing()));
            } catch (Exception ex) { }
        });

        valueAnimator.start();
    }
}

private static float computeRotation(float fraction, float start, float end) {
    float normalizeEnd = end - start; // rotate start to 0
    float normalizedEndAbs = (normalizeEnd + 360) % 360;

    float direction = (normalizedEndAbs > 180) ? -1 : 1; // -1 = anticlockwise, 1 = clockwise
    float rotation;
    if (direction > 0) {
        rotation = normalizedEndAbs;
    } else {
        rotation = normalizedEndAbs - 360;
    }

    float result = fraction * rotation + start;
    return (result + 360) % 360;
}
```

how to solve this?

Comment: Two approaches: 1.) You could ignore the rotation in the event it is exactly 0, or 2.) you could save the previous marker location, and ignore the rotation in the event the lat/long of the current location is exactly equal to that of the previous location.

Comment: @greble31 you mean if (getBearing != 0) {
marker.setRotation(computeRotation(v, startRotation, destination.getBearing()));
}else{
//do nothing
}...?

Comment: Yes, maybe I should have said "bearing" instead of "rotation".